# Not able to open files stored in pendrive

Tags: windows, macos, usb, usb-drive

I had several important which I had downloaded on my MAC and stored it in a pendrive. Now I am using a windows laptop. When i connected my USB device to open the files, I am not able to do so. 
The file names have a ._ in front of their filename and the icons look semi transparent instead of bold. How can I open these files now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are what are generally referred to as invisible files. You can either remove the ._ by renaming them. You can do this with a couple of different software but I recommend [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) since its free and open-source. This is apparently a bug of some network shares